# How does Yarn resolve conflicting dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I am new to Yarn. I wonder how it resolves dependencies if I have package A and B in package.json where package A depends on package C@1.0.0 and package B depends on package C@2.0.0. Would it include both version which will bloat up the build?